# What effect does changing the hub to night-time have?

Tags: lego-pirates-of-the-caribbean

I discovered, mostly by accident, that you can switch from day to night at the hub by

> spinning the ship's wheel at the clock tower

Aside from the obvious of darkening the sky, what in-game effect does this have?

Answer (score 3):

Some characters are only available during the day and some are only available at night.

Comment: Could you elaborate by giving some examples?

Comment: I don't have any specific examples, unfortunately.  From my experience (which was a while ago and on the Xbox), if it was night, then more "bad" characters were outside roaming around, and more "good" characters during the day.  On the Xbox, there was also an achievement (Green Flash) that could be unlocked by changing day to night (there were other ways to unlock the achievement as well as this one).

Answer (score 0):

It has no effect - other than cosmetic maybe, or seeing the pirates in their skeletal form.